Enable the Microsoft Office LTSC PLUS 2024 add-on store without being an administrator
I installed Microsoft Office LTSC PLUS 2024 but apparently it doesn't let me use it with liberta without being an administrator, I would like to install add-ons, it tells me that it is disabled by the administrator, is there a way to skip this step without being an administrator, I don't know through regedit or some script, thanks

I know, but it is the version that Microsoft makes available to technicians for testing, it could not be updated already testing regedit, I changed the password to be able to use the update function, what I need is to enable the plugins

As @John states, you need to explain to administration that the assigned task is unrealistic, Other users would not be able to use "liberta" (Do you mean Libertas?) unless that user has Admin privileges, so your machine would be set up differently from users and would not be the basis for testing.

If you get the message shown in following image, it means Office store may be disabled via group policy. This is a high-level forcing operation via your administrator.


The corresponding registry path is Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\wef\trustedcatalogs,
Value Name  disableomexcatalogs
Value Type  REG_DWORD
Enabled Value   1
Disabled Value  0


